# Does bokeh have axvspan and axhspan?

Tags: python, bokeh

Or anything similar to [axvspan and axhspan](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhspan)

I'm quite fond of those tools in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [`BoxAnnotation`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#box-annotations):

```
p.add_layout(BoxAnnotation(top=80, fill_alpha=0.1, fill_color='red'))
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna give the quad glyph a try then!

Comment: Great. FYI the PR was merged. It will be in a dev-build next week and the 0.9.3 release is planned at the end of the month.

Comment: And here's the [box annotation example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/box_annotation.html) from the bokeh gallery.